# 7z "incorrect command line" when applying encryption

Tags: encryption, zip, 7zip

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and I have installed p7zip, using sudo apt-get.

However, when trying to encrypt a file, using the command below, I get an "incorrect command line" output:

```
 7zr a -mhe=on -phello abc.7z abc.txt
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: This question is off-topic, because it is not programming related. You should have self-answered on [su].

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install p7zip-full package.

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Then, use the following command:

```
7z a -mhe=on -phello abc.7z abc.txt
```

"Everything is Ok" was the output and file abc.txt was encrypted and stored in abc.7z.